# Search within all fields of a table in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am excited to ask my first question here on the site ...
There is a table that contains 5 fields - customer name, phone 1, phone 2, phone 3, phone 4. I type in a phone and want to search if there is such a customer. I need to write a query using the existing CHEKFHON function that will go through all the fields of all the columns of the phones.
Thanks !

Comment: At first glance this doesn't seem difficult - just create a query that searches each of the fields.  What have you tried so far?  What problems are you experiencing with your own attempt?

Comment: The question doesn't include any attempt to solve the problem. [Try to solve your own problem first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users), your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please show what you've tried and any specific roadblock you're running into with [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). For more information [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: The question does not make much sense: either you have an existing function which iterates through all phone columns or you need to write a query which checks all phone columns. Furthermore "all fields of a table" would mean you have to check the customer name as well...